# 2010 Access Runtime - Missing functions for 2007 users?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an Access database for which I have created a 2010 runtime version.

I sent over to a partner in India where their predominant machines only have Access 2007 installed.

They have installed Access 2010 Runtime to these machines, but make the following claims:

1. No access to Nav Pane - to see/open tables
2. No menu ribbon
3. No table/datasheet right-click functions (sort, find, etc.), except as I have implemented under buttons on the form.

I see all these functions when I run on a 2010 VM.  I don;t have a 2007-only machine to validate or debug their claims.

Does this result sound odd?

I suppose I could work around some of these:

1. Populate the current list of tables in a listbox on the form
2. Create a custom menu with the necessary functions
3. Not too sure about the table/datasheet right click functions

Not freaking out just yet, but getting close...  I cannot re-build this thing DOWN to 2007.

Any advice anyone?

Comment: When you say that you "have created a 2010 runtime version" do you mean an `.accde` file? If so, try temporarily renaming it from `.accde` to `.accdr` and open it in Access 2010 to see what it looks like. (`.accdr` files automatically open in "runtime" mode.)

Comment: Yes, I created a .accde file and confirmed the India team launched this file, not the original .accdb

Comment: Renamed and clicked .accdr.  Confirms their claims.  No Nav Pane, No Menu bar.  Right-click functions are available, but under the column header drop-down arrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this result sound odd?

Not really. It sounds like you were opening the `.accde` file using the full Access 2010 application while the other team was opening it using the Access 2010 Runtime.

The Access 2010 Runtime environment does not include things like the standard ribbons, navigation pane, etc.. If the developer intends to deploy the Access application under the Runtime then the expectation is that they will provide custom ribbons and navigation tools as required for that particular application.

Note that this is true whether the Access application is distributed as an `.accdb` file or an `.accde` file. An `.accde` file is simply an `.accdb` file with the VBA source code removed and the users being prevented from opening objects like Forms and Reports in Design View. Those changes help "lock down" an application when opened in the full Access application, but they don't make any difference to the behaviour when opened in the Runtime environment (because the users can't perform those operations in the Runtime environment anyway).

Developers can test the "Runtime" behaviour of their applications by opening them in "Runtime mode" in the full Access application. This can be accomplished in either of the following ways:

1. Create a shortcut that invokes `MSACCESS.EXE` with the `/runtime` switch and passes the name of the `.accdb` file to open.
2. Temporarily rename the `.accdb` file to `.accdr` and open it. `.accdr` files automatically open in Runtime mode.

Comment: So, do I need to manually add back custom Menus/Shortcuts - will they appear in the RT version?

Comment: Answer is yes, and its turns out to be not very complicated!